# Why is the number of occupied cores higher than the threadpool size?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a reason that the number of cores occupied by a Java program is higher than the size of the threadpool? I am specifying the threadpool size to be 4, but yet I see that my java code occupies 6 or 7 cores after a while (i.e. top shows 600). I have 8 cores on this machine. Am I doing something wrong or is java deciding to automatically use the other unused cores when it does multithreading? If yes, is there any way to force the number of cores being used during multithreading?

The piece of code I am using looks like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   executor.execute(do something);                
}
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}
```

Comment: Could it be the GC thread?

Comment: Side note: you should be using [`ExecutorService#awaitTermination()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

Comment: 4 runnable plus GC plus Main thread.

Comment: I see. It makes sense if it's the GC and the Main threads. How many GC thread a java program can have?

Comment: Just adding an interesting observation: top shows a cpu usage percentage which is higher than the number of cores. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JVM uses several system threads, like Finalizer thread. Run jconsole, connect to your running app, go to Threads tab and you will see all running threads. Or add this code to your app

```
    for(Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

Comment: @Evegeniy This shows only the thread created by JVM. For example, the above prints 5 threads, but the task manager shows 10 threads for the process. Are the remaining threads are native threads not created by JVM?

Comment: @gammay extra threads are created by JMX agent when we connect to JVM from jconsole

Comment: I am not using jconsole. I just ran a sample Java program and noticed the thread count in Task Manager (I used Windows)

Comment: I would put it this way: those extra native threads are threads started by JVM but not mapped to Java Threads